# Typescript can not recognize the methods of passed-this as a callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class inside my Typescript project that calls a function from another Typescript file.

> I simplified the main problem and it can also be copied and pasted in the IDE

```js
// File one
const classA = new A("/hello")

// File two
class A {
  endpoint: string;

  constructor(endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint
  }

  login() {
    return 1
  }

  register() {
    return 2
  }

  connect() {
    // instead of sending login and register method, I want to send created-this-class-instance
    // I do not want to send like this: checkConection(() => this.login(), () => register())
    // Because the number of functions increases and I want to use the instance 
    // that has been created and not create a new instance class again. 
    checkConection(this)
  }
}

// File Three
const checkConection = ("Aresponse", instance: A) => {
  console.log(instance.login())
  console.log(instance.register())
}
```

It should be noted if I do this:

```js
const checkConection = (res: string, instance: A) => {}
```

it works, but how can create a generic type for `checkConection` function
?

when I do this:

```js
const checkConection = <T>(res: string, instance: T) => {}
```

It shows me `Property 'sendMessage' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into their own IDEs and demonstrate your issue for our ourselves, without any unrelated problems.  You could do this by first testing in a standalone IDE like the TypeScript Playground, resolving any issues there (except for the one you're asking about) and then pasting the final example code back here as plaintext.  (e.g., right now `this.socket` doesn't refer to anything. That's not an exhaustive list of the issues, just one that jumps out at you.)  I'll take another look if that happens. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Hi, Thank you for suggestion. At the end of the post, I put an update title in which I simplified the whole problem. It is a typescript project

Comment: How come you cannot use simple inheritance or an interface defining the methods you expect to have? `interface B { method(): returnType; }`, `class A implements B {}`? Then `checkConnection(res: string, instance: B) => {}`?

Comment: @Tatsh I need to do this with Generic type, the way you suggestion I did in my simple code

Comment: See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0xRRm).  You can use generics for `checkConnection` but it's not clear *why*, since they are not necessary for the example.  In order for the example to be a [mre], it should demonstrate the reason why a non-generic function wouldn't work for you. Oh and I had to fix some things in there (annotation and a missing argument) that you aren't asking about so you might want to [edit] those in.  How should we proceed here?